# Error preloading images in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, loading

I am using this code to preload image and reference them later by id.
It's working in most browsers and on ipad, but IE8 generates this error:

**'Unable to get property 'target' of undefined null reference'**

This is my code:

```
var images = [{id:"kids", url:"assets/driekids.png"}, {id:"title",url:"assets/gametitle.png"}];
var assets = [];
var fnCallback = fn;
var loaded = 0;

this.startLoading = function() {
    var t = this;
    for(var i = 0;i<images.length;i++){
        var r = new Image();
        r.src = images[i].url;
        r.name = images[i].id;
        r.onload = function(){t.checkLoaded();};
    }
}

this.checkLoaded = function(e) {    
    this.assets[e.target.name] = e.target;  
    loaded++;
    if(loaded == images.length) fnCallback();       
}
```

My question: is this way of image preloading, by using new Image(), possible on IE8?

Answer (score 1):

In IE you get the event object like this:

```
window.event
```

so you will have to make modifications to your code:

```
this.startLoading = function() {
    var t = this;
    for(var i = 0;i<images.length;i++){
        var r = new Image();
        r.src = images[i].url;
        r.name = images[i].id;
        r.onload = t.checkLoaded; // you dont want an anonymous function here
    }
}

this.checkLoaded = function(e) {
    // get the event object for both IE and other browsers
    var event = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || event.srcElement ;
    this.assets[target.name] = target;  
    loaded++;
    if(loaded == images.length) fnCallback();       
}
```

Comment: Could I use "if(!e) e = window.event;" ?

Comment: @PietBinnenbocht in your example `e` is always undefined, because you never pass it to the handler.

Comment: @PietBinnenbocht see my example above

Comment: Thanks, you put me in the right direction. I also changed the onload code to "$(img).bind(“load” ...)". It's now working in IE9 and IE10.
Only in IE8 the "target" doesn't have the "name" property, so I can't reference the image by using this.assets["title"]